# CS 193P Winter 2010 - HelloPoly (my polygons are out of bound)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, variable-assignment

Part of my polygons are drawn outside of the bound and I dun understand why.

This is what i mean:

[Image 1 (octagon)](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6805/screenshot20101218atam0.png)

Except for Square and Hexagon, the rest of the polygons have parts which are drawn out of bound.

I printed out the coordinates for some of them generated from the (pointsForPolygonInRect) method and this is what i got ...

> For 3-sided (triangle) :
>
> "NSPoint: {139.99998, **-16**}",
>
> "NSPoint: {249.1192, 172.99998}",
>
> "NSPoint: {30.880798, 173}"

Notice the "-16" y-value, I don't understand how the (pointsForPolygonInRect) method produce negative values, is the algorithm wrong ?

I am very sure I copied and paste the original code which was given in the assignment #3 directly into my PolygonView Class, did not modify it, and still got the same error.

> For 8-sided (octagon):
>
> "NSPoint: {256.40881, 158.21811}",
>
> "NSPoint: {188.21811, **226.40881**}",
>
> "NSPoint: {91.781876, **226.40881**}",
>
> "NSPoint: {23.591179, 158.21812}",
>
> "NSPoint: {23.591179, 61.781887}",
>
> "NSPoint: {91.781921,
>   **-6.4088364**}",
>
> "NSPoint: {188.21814,
>   **-6.4088135**}",
>
> "NSPoint: {256.40884, 61.781944}"

Notice the negative value also for octagon, also the height for my PolygonView class is only 220, I don't understand how the method output 226.40881 which cause the top and bottom line to go out of bound.

Below is the drawRect and pointsForPolygonInRect code (both are inside the PolyView Class) ...

```
- (NSArray *)pointsForPolygonInRect:(CGRect)rect numberOfSides:(int)numberOfSides { 
     CGPoint center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2.0, rect.size.height / 2.0); 
     float radius = 0.9 * center.x; 
     NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
     float angle = (2.0 * M_PI) / numberOfSides; 
     float exteriorAngle = M_PI - angle; 
     float rotationDelta = angle - (0.5 * exteriorAngle);
     for (int currentAngle = 0; currentAngle < numberOfSides; currentAngle++) { 
         float newAngle = (angle * currentAngle) - rotationDelta; 
         float curX = cos(newAngle) * radius; 
         float curY = sin(newAngle) * radius;
         [result addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + curX, center.y + curY)]];
     } 
 return result;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
    NSArray *arrayOfCoordinates = [self pointsForPolygonInRect:[self bounds]  numberOfSides:[polygon numberOfSides]];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [arrayOfCoordinates objectEnumerator];

    CGContextRef ct = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    NSLog(@"%@", arrayOfCoordinates);    // for checking purposes

    CGPoint firstCoordinatePoint = [[enumerator nextObject] CGPointValue];
    CGContextBeginPath(ct);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ct, firstCoordinatePoint.x, firstCoordinatePoint.y);

    CGPoint nextCoordinatePoint;
    NSValue *coordinate;
    while (coordinate = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        nextCoordinatePoint = [coordinate CGPointValue];
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ct, nextCoordinatePoint.x, nextCoordinatePoint.y);
    } 
    CGContextClosePath(ct);

    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextDrawPath(ct, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

I greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing you're doing wrong, it's the algorithm used in `pointsForPolygonInRect:numberOfSides:`

The way it's written it wants the PolygonView to be square (or close to it).  Notice it calculates the center point, then bases the radius on the x component of the center.  Meaning, if your PolygonView is wider than it is tall, it's going to end up truncating points at the top and bottom.

I took 193P in '08 or '09, and did the same assignment, and my code is basically identical to yours.  Here's mine as I originally wrote it:
https://img.skitch.com/20101218-c6df66k52ss5a1nnci88ek2a2d.jpg

If I make my PolygonView shorter than it is wide, it ends up looking like yours does:
https://img.skitch.com/20101218-ptjh5kmkwcrm9fsqustpfft2qj.jpg

Solution?  Make your PolygonView taller, or narrower.  Or, if you're really a stud, modify the algorithm in `pointsForPolygonInRect:numberOfSides` to better handle non-square views.  :)  (Hint: you only need to change one line of code.)

Comment: Darn, so the one they create only work for square views. They should name the method as pointsForPolygonInSquare instead of Rect. :/ one line of code :). Thanks I will try it out first.

Comment: Thanks zpasternack. I added this 
float radius = 0.9 * (center.x < center.y ? center.x : center.y);
so that, the smaller of the two will be used instead :)

Answer (score 0):

(Second time lucky!)

If it helps, this is the code I wrote to create the path when I did this same assignment two years ago:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
BOOL drawing = NO;
for (NSValue *value in points) {
    CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
    if (!drawing) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
        drawing = YES;
    } else {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
    }
}
CGContextClosePath(context);
```

Comment: Hi d11wtq, thanks for your code. I tried yours, it build and run normally, but some parts of the polygon as i mention above still appear out of bound. I am puzzled.

Comment: I never did any `NSLog()` calls on the points at the time, so it may have been the same for me.  Does it render ok?  Since the view is positioned in the middle of the screen, and is smaller than the screen, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: You mean NSLog(@"%@", arrayOfCoordinates)? It just for me to check the points. Then I realized some of them are out of bound, such as the negative y-values.

Comment: I just ran mine again for the first time since coding it.  Much to my surprise it works :P  I NSLogged the point values and nothing is out of bounds.  Here's the whole project for reference: http://w3style.co.uk/~d11wtq/HelloPoly.zip

Comment: Just change the Base SDK in the build settings (and also check it in the dropdown at the top-left of the window).